# mass convert Excel files into tab-delimited text files

Tags: excel

Is there a tool to convert a large number of excel files into tab delimted files automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just through this together, its not pretty but should do what you need. Tested on WindowsXP / Office2007.

download from: http://stembro.byethost17.com/utility_scripts/xl2tab/xl2tab.html

Extract the xl2tab.vbs file to the directory containing the excel files and double-click to run. It will place the converted files into a new directory called "output." The original directory-structure remains intact within the output folder.

Comment: sorry no direct link to the file, my host doesn't allow hotlinking. Can't complain when it's free =)

Comment: thank you I will try it!  is it possible to loop through all sub directories recursively?

Comment: I just uploaded an updated version that will loop through all sub-directories. It outputs everything to a folder called "output", which keeps the original directory structure intact. The download is in the same place as before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any good free tools to do so right now, but you could look into using the Open Office API to write something,

[http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=7657&highlight=convert+xls+csv+command+line][1]

Or for a quick and dirty solution, you could record and Open Office Calc macro that would do it, and launch that macro from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This might also help http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

convert to csv, and maybe replace , with tabs?